# Drupal authenticated user unable to log out

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-cache

I have been trying to find a solution to a problem I have been having with this new drupal site I created. I created various users with different roles to test that the permissions they are given are in order, and a problem popped up. This has been tested in IE and Opera, Firefox doesn't seem to have this problem. If I am logged in as an authenicated user I can view specific data like, certain views, certain pages, etc. After I logout and become anonymous, I can browse around, restricted of course, but in a few seconds I find that the user is logged in again.

Drupal Version: 6.20
I checked this link here ([after logout some pages are show as logged in? #86](http://drupal.org/node/197786)) and it looked promising, but there was no definitive solution. This link ([Session doesn't expire on user logout!](http://drupal.org/node/891038)) also pointed to the fact that it may be a caching issue, but after following the instructions in the first link no solution has been reached.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
function hook_user($op, & $edit, & $account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'logout':
      cache_clear_all();
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also am not sure, I did have a problem and CTRL+F5 was the answer at the time, so I think it was definitely cache related, and yes I had tabs open all over the place

However, in case it helps, I then installed the **[masquerade module](http://drupal.org/project/masquerade)** which allows me switch back and fore between the various user roles I created, this was brilliant when first developing and testing

I disabled it when finished, but soon re-enabled it, as it still has the useful purpose in that if a user does have a problem I can (admin permission only) can masquerade as them to "see what they see"

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the prob if you only have one browser with one tab open? Sometimes I run into issues if I have loads of browsers and tabs open, and I've been logging in and out as various users here and there.

This probably isn't your issue, but I thought I'd mention it just in case... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database for Drupal, you can:

1) Open 'users' table
 2) Find the row of the user you are currently logged in as
 3) set 'status' field to 0 (1 being active, 0 being blocked)
 4) save this update to the table
 5) refresh the web page and you should be redirected to the login screen.

If you log in as admin you may change modify the user status from blocked back using 'People' tab!

Comment: don't do this. You will be sad if you block/unblock users.  TRUNCATE the sessions table instead.